# Создание пользователей в Samba

Tags: samba, active-directory, users, linux

Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно ли добавление пользователей только в парольный файл smbpasswd (без заведения пользователя в системе и /etc/passwd)?

В одном случае нужно запаролить сетевую папку для двух-трёх человек, это ещё терпимо, но как задумаюсь, что нужно будет делать файлопомойку на несколько десятков тысяч пользователей АД, которые можно перенести в Самбу, но из за этого ограничения - надо заводить каждого пользователя в систему с /etc/passwd, строго идентичными с АД...

Может я не замечаю простого решения?

Comment: так добавьте файлопомойку в AD используйте AD сервер как сервер авторизации как-то так https://wiki.debian.org/AuthenticatingLinuxWithActiveDirectory (там с вариантами, общий смысл - пользователи в AD, еще есть скрипты для создания хомов пользователей при авторизации из AD)

Comment: @eicto, В данный момент всё так и устроено, но фирма движется в сторону лицензирования всего чего только можно, а лицензии на файлопомойки с огромным количеством юзерей, внешние НАТы, итд - дорогое удовольствие. Поэтому фирма рассматривает вариант перебросить всё это на линукс с самбой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дак дайте всем юзерам один акк и пусть с него заходят. Если же надо всех логировать, да еще и несколько десятков человек, то должен быть LDAP сервер, хотя бы... ИМХО

Comment: В случае с АД - один акк не рассматривается. Нужно чтобы разные пользователи видели разные папки. Логгировать не нужно вообще. Просто возможны разные доступы.

Comment: АД если это Active Directory. То гуглите что-то типо [LDAP][1]

[1]: https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=LDAP+Linux+home+directory+&qscrl=1

Comment: Я так надеялся обойти его стороной, наклепав необходимых пользователей в самбе. Но нет так нет...

Comment: Обойти стороной можно разными путями, но это все будут костыли, которые рано или позно выстрелят в колено. Лучше сразу делать все правильно.